# How to directly open the Desktop in a Live Ubuntu image?

Tags: installation, live-usb

I put Ubuntu on a USB stick using [LinuxLiveUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

It works great, but upon start-up a dialog box for installing Ubuntu comes up asking if one wants to install it or to just continue to use it.  It stops the start-up process, and if you click it closed it then shows you the desktop.

Can anyone advise me how to just boot straight into the desktop by getting rid of this dialog box?

This is definitely after the start-up, so I think it must be in an init.d script someplace.

Comment: Please, take a look at the [meta page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) to see how this site work. If you think that any answer has responds to your issue, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) so this question remains as *answered*. Also, you can upvote any answer that you think useful.

Answer (score 0):

For what I believe, editing the bootloader file will work out, because from there you can choose wether to try or to install.

Comment: And where is the bootloader file located?

Comment: Can you give advice on what it would look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are trying to use a LiveUSB as a [full installation of Ubuntu inside a USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/q/16988/62483).

Concepts:

- The LiveUSB is used to try Ubuntu and to install Ubuntu in a HDD.
- The USB stick with a **full** Ubuntu installation can be booteable and is
  used to run Ubuntu *daily*.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @user142859 Please, take a look at the [meta page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) to see how this site work. If you think that any answer has responds to your issue, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) so this question remains as *answered*. Also, you can upvote any answer that you think useful.